# What does this symbol mean in this context?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have read a paper about `Proof that every set can be well-ordered` by Ernst Zermelo. But I cannot figure out what this symbol mean in this definition? I have used the red mark mark this symbol. And I have another question: how can I search for this kind of problem? I even don't know the name of this symbol.

[image: n_m]

Comment: $\aleph_0$ ("aleph-naught") is the smallest infinite cardinal, the cardinality of the set of natural numbers.

Comment: As a side note,  this proof inherently uses the Axiom of Choice, and in fact the two principles are equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for such symbols, you can try [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) or [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/). Both worked for $\aleph$ when I tried. Also, usually you could search for the term used, in this case [Cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality).

Answer (score 2):

That is the Hebrew letter "aleph" $\aleph$. The subscript zero means we read the letter $\aleph_0$ as "aleph null." It canonically denotes the cardinality of a countably infinite set, namely the natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$.